# Exception handling in for-loop / EAFP

Tags: python, exception, coding-style

I have a request with JSON data, it may or may not contain `'items'` key, if it does it has to be a list of objects, that I want to process individually. So I have to write something like:

```
json_data = request.get_json()
for item in json_data['items']:
    process_item(item)
```

But, since presence of the `'items'` key is not mandatory, an additional measure needs to be taken. I would like to follow [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2.7/glossary.html#term-eafp) approach, so wrapping it up into `try ... except` statement:

```
json_data = request.get_json()
try:
    for item in json_data['items']:
        process_item(item)
except KeyError as e:
    pass
```

Let's assume that a `KeyError` exception can happened inside the `process_item(...)` function, that may indicate a code error, thus it should not go unnoticed, so I want to make sure that I will catch only exceptions coming from `for` statement predicate, as a workaround I came up with:

```
json_data = request.get_json()
try:
    for item in json_data['items']:
        process_item(item)
except KeyError as e:
    if e.message != 'items':
        raise e
    pass
```

But

1. It looks ugly
2. It relies on knowledge of the `process_item(...)` implementation, assuming that `KeyError('items')` cannot be raised inside of it.
3. If the `for` statement becomes more complex e.g. `for json_data['raw']['items']` so will the `except` clause making it even less readable and maintainable.

**Update:**
The suggested alternative

```
json_data = request.get_json()
try:
    items = json_data["items"]
except KeyError:
    items = []

for item in items:
    process_item(item)
```

is essentially the same as

```
json_data = request.get_json()
if json_data.has('items')
    items = json_data['items']
else:
    items = []

for item in items:
    process_item(item)
```

So we check before we loop. I would like to know if there is any more pythonic/EAFP approach?

Answer (score 1):

You can catch the exception only when accessing `"items"`:

```
json_data = request.get_json()
try:
    items = json_data["items"]
except KeyError:
    items = []
for item in items:
    process_item(item)
```

However, we can replace the try-block with a call to the [`.get()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) function, making it much cleaner:

```
for item in request.get_json().get("items", []):
    process_item(item)
```

Comment: Not only is the get() approach shorter in terms of lines of code, but it is also much less error prone. There are many exception handling schemes that each have their own draw-backs.  In particular you always need to be sure that an exception is raised for the reason you think it is, before you go ahead and catch it. With this in mind, it is always safe (though not always necessary) to avoid the exception in the first place.

Comment: @univerio it is the same as defensive style, you iterate the list only once you check it is iterable. There is nothing wrong with it, and I often end up doing like: for item in items.get('key1', {}).get('key2', []) if I need to reach a nested element, but I would like to see if there is a more pythonic/EAFP way of doing so.

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest option is to use a`try`block around only the code that attempts to retrieve the data associated with the`'items'`key:

```
json_data = request.get_json()
try:
    items = json_data['items']
except KeyError:
    print "no 'items' to process"  # or whatever you want to...
else:
    for item in items:
        process_item(item)
```

This layout will allow to you clearly separate the error handling as you see fit. You can add a separate independent`try`/`except`around the`for`loop if desired.